# How to get a multi-level menu work in hugo with theme "dot"?

Tags: html, web, drop-down-menu, generator, hugo

I'm currently building a web site with hugo using the theme "dot" and having trouble regarding the menu.

Now I want to have a menu at the top of the page with main menu points and opening sub menus when hovering over the main entries. So far, so good no problem, that is easy using the config file defining the menu in there. But, the main menu points are not clickable when naming the ".md" files after their meaning. When I name the main entry points "index.md" in their specific folder then I get other problems like not properly working sub menu entries.

An appropriate option would also be to have a main menu at the top of the page and when clicking on an item apart from the contents of that specific main menu item, a side navigation menu opens up and shows the menu items of that specific main menu (not just all menu items). I don't know how to implement this as the specific content pages are ".md" files.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best regards,
Jochen

Comment: Hi Jochen, when you have questions about someone's specific theme. In this case "dot" it would be best to post on that themes github board or etc. As this isn't really about Hugo, it's regarding a specific implementation.

Comment: I.e. Go here: https://github.com/themefisher/dot-hugo-documentation-theme

Comment: Thanks for your comment Rogelio. The point is that there's only paid support as far as I understood it. Do you know any Theme allowing multi-level pull down menu with clickable top items? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Theirs the triangle - cost, speed, quality - you can have good cost (free) and good quality, but it's going to take some time, you can have it fast, and cheap, but quality is going to be bad. I would suggest you start the hard way and learn hugo. Once you get the understanding, it's a phenomenal toolset (I develop sites with Hugo and have never been able to use a 3rd party theme for this reason), for a basic intro I would suggest the Giraffe academy youtube videos for hugo.

Comment: Otherwise, your entire existence with Hugo will be a continuous process of requesting assistance for that little tweak you need to someone else's theme... and that sounds not what you or anyone would want.